# How to resend unsent email with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email

Is there any boilerplate code of how to resend unsent email (if there was any error) with Laravel? Should I use queues for that?

Comment: What sort of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A queue is what you need.

Add the recipients, subject, body, etc to a queue. And have a job that:

1. Tries to send the email
2. Remove from queue if successful
3. Keep in queue if unsuccessful